# leetcode 212 word search II bugs using trie

Tags: algorithm, recursion, backtracking

Problem:
Given an m x n board of characters and a list of strings words, return all words on the board.

Each word must be constructed from letters of sequentially adjacent cells, where adjacent cells are horizontally or vertically neighboring. The same letter cell may not be used more than once in a word.
[image]
Here is my solution:

```
class Solution(object):
    def findWords(self, board, words):
        WORD_KEY = '$'
        trie = {}
        for word in words:
            node = trie
            for letter in word:
                # retrieve the next node; If not found, create a empty node.
                node = node.setdefault(letter, {})
            # mark the existence of a word in trie node
            node[WORD_KEY] = word
        
        rowNum = len(board)
        colNum = len(board[0])
        
        matchedWords = []
        
        def helper(row,col,trie):
            if trie.keys()[0]==WORD_KEY:
                matchedWords.append(trie[WORD_KEY])
                return
            if row>len(board)-1 or row<0 or col>len(board[0])-1 or col<0:
                return
            if board[row][col] == '*':
                return
            if board[row][col] in trie:
                for (rowOffset, colOffset) in [(-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1)]:
                    temp=board[row][col]
                    board[row][col]='*'
                    helper(row+rowOffset,col+colOffset,trie[temp])
                    board[row][col]=temp
            else:
                return
         
        for i in range(len(board)):
            for j in range(len(board[0])):
                helper(i,j,trie) 
        return matchedWords
```

Recursion is always my biggest issue, and it is hard to find the mistake, I Want to know how I get it wrong with my code. The wrong output is such below:
["oath","oath","oath","oath","eat","eat","eat","eat"], each repeated 4 times

instead of just
[oath,eat]

Comment: would better if you also add the problem description here..

Comment: it is leetcode number 212, https://leetcode.com/problems/word-search-ii/

Comment: @bot99zjc add the problem description to the question, rather than adding a link to it

Comment: @bot99zjc your program has some problems - including last statement  exposed a formatting issue. Please check my revised one in the Post.

Comment: @DanielHao where is the exact problem of my code?

Comment: @bot99zjc - can you read the working code and compare with yours? It's fairly easy and you can learn more by digging it yourself.